# How can I test the way my website looks on an iPad or another device without owning the device?

Tags: asp.net, ipad, ios-simulator

We need to test our asp.net website on an iPad, how can we do is without having an actual iPad on hand.

Note : we only have Windows machines.

Comment: When i didn't have an ipad or itouch i used media queries with safari browser to test, i also went to the mac store to test it there !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some great info in this slide deck on the entire process, including emulators for testing:

http://www.slideshare.net/firt/mobile-web-html5-performance-optimization

Comment: I guess I'll try the adobe air app emulator. We need to buy a Mac and download Xcode.